# npm run stryker fails Error: Cannot find module 'mutation-testing-report-schema/dist/src/api'

Tags: node.js, mutation-testing, stryker

Stryker started failing because of unloaded module 'mutation-testing-report-schema/dist/src/api'. I tried deleting node_modules and npm clean install.

Here is my dependency list:

```
"@stryker-mutator/core": "^1.2.0",
"@stryker-mutator/html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
"@stryker-mutator/javascript-mutator": "^1.2.0",
"@stryker-mutator/jest-runner": "^1.2.0",
```

Here is the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mutation-testing-report-schema/dist/src/api'
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'my_project/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/api/report.js',
    'my_project/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/src/ScoreResultCalculator.js',
    'my_project/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/src/Stryker.js',
    'my_project/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/src/StrykerCli.js',
    'my_project/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/bin/stryker'
```

]